# How to change file text content only with Shell Script commands?

Tags: boot, command-line, scripts, luks

In a file, there is:

`sd5_crypt UUID=1337 none luks,discard`

I'd like to change it to:

```
sd5_crypt UUID=1337 /dev/disk/by-label/MON_LABEL_ICI:/keyfile luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

**with a Shell script.**

I dont know (blind) if it is sd5, sd4 or sx999... I dont know the UUID.

I have to change all what is after 1337.
Well, said humanly "I delete all after the UUID number - I dunno it - and replace with `/dev/dis/by-label....` which I know.

I dont know which is the good solution. Can you help please ?

Comment: If there is only the line you posted in a file, you can use something like: `sed -e 's/none luks,discard/YOURPATH luks,THEREST/g'`

Comment: Thank you. Why `-e` not `-i ?`

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry, I messed these up

Comment: @Wayne_Yux that YOURPATH part contains forward slashes. Might want to escape those with backslash

Comment: @serg yes of course. I think I will turn my comment into an answer and expand it a bit

Comment: I did, works !! but Ì use `-i`

Comment: @Wayne_Yux yes, that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanded version of my comment:

You can use `sed` to edit your file. In general you need:

```
sed 's/STRING/REPLACEMENT/g'
```

In your example the following code should work for you:

With explanation:

```
sed -i                # the -i option allows you to read from and write to the same file
's/none luks,discard/ # the part you want to replace
\/dev\/disk\/by-label\/MON_LABEL_ICI:\/keyfile luks,keyscript=\/lib\/cryptsetup\/scripts\/passdev/g'
                     # the part you want to insert. Note, that the / characters
                     # have to be escaped with \/
 input.txt           # your input file
```

as one-liner without comments to copy-paste:

```
sed -i 's/none luks,discard/\/dev\/disk\/by-label\/MON_LABEL_ICI:\/keyfile luks,keyscript=\/lib\/cryptsetup\/scripts\/passdev/g' input.txt
```

Comment: not sure you need quotes 's/.../.../g'

Comment: It s working but I bet there is a safer way, imagine a system where it is `none luks, discard` (note the *space* after the comma). In such a case it fails. In the future I'll detect the second space (after UUID) and replace all after, with some copy, concatenate, paste.

Comment: you can also use two sed commands like `sed 's/none/FIRST/g' | sed 's/discard/SECOND/g'` then you don't have to look for spaces after all